# Error shown when deleting products created via webservice from prestashop 8.1.2

Tags: prestashop

I have strange issue and can not find the cause. I have PrestaShop 8.1.2 (fresh instance) with only template installed. If I create product from panel I can delete it and it's confirmed my "success" message. But If I create products using PS Services API and try to delete them from the panel, they are being deleted but got an error message:

> "There was an error deleting object".

There is no more information regarding which object could not be deleted, no error in Apache logs, event turning on devmode does not give any more information.

In that situation I am not sure if products were imported properly and would not give me any other errors in the future.
By the way, I use same import script in another shop running 1.7.8 and there is no such issue.

What could be the cause of such message?

I have compared script to another PrestaShop and it works fine in older version.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I have figured that out (don't blame me- I have dug the internet for a week before posting my question, and find solution right after that :)

So the problem is that when I take schema from webservice, and fill only few nodes I need, it will create meaningless rows in two tables where it should not: ps_product_attachment and ps_product_attribute. It is obvious bug becouse I set product type to "standard" and even thou presta creates rows for "combination".

Solution is to blank all nodes before filling the right ones.

```
$blankXml = $webService->get(['url' => $adres_api.'api/products?schema=blank']);

$produkt = $blankXml->product->children();
foreach ($produkt as $nodeKey => $node)
{
    $produkt->$nodeKey = "";
}
```